# Django: Can't GROUP BY on a template table

Tags: python, django, templates, aggregate, annotate

I'm trying to show a table in the template, which shows transactions with their dates.

The query is:

```
resultado = Asiento.objects.filter(
    Empresa=request.session['codEmp'],
    codcta=cod_cta
).exclude(anulado='S').order_by(date)
```

But the user can check a checkbox which if set to true should show one row per date in the table.

Without group by:

```
+-------------------------------+-------+
|  date  | trans_in | trans_out | total |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
|2019/5/3| $5.000   |    $0     | $5.000|
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
|2019/5/3|   $0     |   $2.500  |-$2.500|
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
|2019/5/4|  $1.000  |    $0     |$1.000 |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

And what I'm trying to do is:

```
+-------------------------------+-------+
|  date  | trans_in | trans_out | total |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
|2019/5/3| $5.000   |  $2.500   |$2.500 |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
|2019/5/4|  $1.000  |    $0     |$1.000 |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

I've already tried by doing

```
resultado = Asiento.objects.filter(
    Empresa=request.session['codEmp'],
    codcta=cod_cta
).exclude(anulado='S').order_by(date).values('date').annotate(
    dcount=Count('date')
)
```

Using annotate but it doesn't work!
I really can't figure yet how to group by easier.

Later in the code I iterate with a for loop over `resultado` to add and substract the amount of money for each object in the queryset.

```
for asiento in resultado:
    add = add+asiento.add
    sub = sub+asiento.sub
    asiento.total = asiento.add-asiento.sub

total = add-sub
```

***UPDATED:***

I progressed in the problem so I'm adding more info in order to get this solved.
The query I'm using is the following one:

```
resultado = Asiento.objects.filter(Empresa=request.session['codEmp'], codcta=cod_cta,
                                                               **query_kwargs).exclude(anulado='S')\
                                .order_by(orden).values('feasto').aggregate(dcount=Count('feasto'),
                                                                            debe=Sum('debe'), haber=Sum('haber'))
```

And it's working fine! The printing of `resultado` is:

```
{'dcount': 3, 'debe': Decimal('27602.23'), 'haber': Decimal('0.00')}
```

Which is correct because the query has three objects, all with the same date and it's adding `debe` (credit) properly.

But now I can't get how to show it properly in the template, since iterating with `{% for asiento in resultado %}` is printing the three rows that have the same date. And I only want **one row** per **similar date**.

Also I can't get these rows attrs that are out of the syntaxis `.values().aggregate()...` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. It's either to total up each date or to sum all totals. I've provided ways to do both.

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Count

resultado = Asiento.objects.filter(
    Empresa=request.session['codEmp'],
    codcta=cod_cta
).exclude(anulado='S').order_by(date).values('date').annotate(
    dcount=Count('date'),
    add_sum=Sum('add'),
    sub_sum=Sum('sub'),
).annotate(
    total=F('add_sum')+F('sub_sum')
)
```

This will give you each date with fields representing add_sum, sub_sum, and total. If you wanted to aggregate all the totals of all dates then you'd want to do then:

```
print(resultado.aggregate(total_all=Sum('total'))['total_all'])
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer @schillingt. I can't get why when I use .values('date').annotate(dcount=Count('date')) and I print the variable with the results, it shows a couple of results with the same value in 'date' field and "'dcount': 1" instead of showing only one and a different ammount value in dcount. I can't get why. Maybe because it's a date field?

Comment: Your answer was right! The issue with my code was that I was including an ".order_by" in the query, which resulted in some non grouped similar dates. I just removed the "order_by" and it worked perfect!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you figured it out.